# My If statement dosn't do what I want it to

Tags: java, android

I have this:

```
int tries;
```

and this:

```
tries = 2;
```

Basically, I want another activity to appear when the user runs out of tries.

Here is whats subtracting from the tries variable:

```
            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tries--;
            triess.setText(tries + "try(s)");
        }
    });
```

But, here is my code:

```
        if (tries == 0) {
        //countDown.cancel();
        //finish();
        Intent openGame = new Intent("com.kyle.expertemoji.loserclass");
        startActivity(openGame);
    }
```

Comment: It's missing code and explanation of problem. What does it do that it shouldn't or not do that it should? Do you get errors?

Comment: The code provided *as-is* won't pass through the `if` statement code. Impossible to answer in its current state. Hope that this comment is not *rude* nor *disrespectful* for you.

Comment: Getting closer. Where is the `if` statement located?

Comment: The if statement should be opening another activity, but it does not. @codeMagic

Comment: I think your if statement needs to go inside the onClick

Comment: I know what it should do but where is it? In the `onClick`?

Comment: @KyleK from your actual code, there's **no** relationship between the `onClick` method and the `if` block. **Please** edit the answer accordingly to show this, otherwise the question will be closed.

Comment: in onCreate @codeMagic

Comment: @KyleK it needs to be in the onClick, onCreate is only called when  the activity is created and never again, so your code will never go back to that if statement.

Comment: this is not all the code, these are just blocks, the actuall code is alot loner, these blocks are the places I'm having problems in. @luiggiMendoza

Comment: @KyleK The problem is that without context it's much, much more difficult to know what's actually happening. For example, the statement `int tries` or `if (tries == 0)` could appear *anywhere* in your code.

Comment: My if statement cannot be in any onClick, if tries starts at 2 and reaches 0 a activity opens. I'm not sure how your suposed to put that in any onClick.

Comment: See the comments in the code I posted below. That should explain it better

Comment: Voting to close based on comment on @codeMagic answer: *I want the if statement to run just whenever. It just needs to be somewhere so that it'll continue checking what tries is equal to* (currently deleted). By the way, you could have a thread with an infinite loop asking about this, but that would be a very bad design. Please review the basic of programmings **or** reformulate your question to show a **design problem** since in its current form looks like a programming problem.

Answer (score 3):

Put the code in the `onClick()` if you want it to run when the user clicks the `Button` as it only runs when the `Activity` is created if it is in `onCreate()`

```
          @Override
    public void onClick(View v) // button is clicked
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tries--;  // tries is decrimented so if it was 1 it is now 0
        triess.setText(tries + "try(s)");

        if (tries == 0)   // this will be true from the comment above and will run the code starting the Activity
        {
            //countDown.cancel();
           //finish();
            Intent openGame = new Intent("com.kyle.expertemoji.loserclass");
            startActivity(openGame);
        }
    }
});
```

If you want the `if` statement to run some other time then indicate when and show that code and we can help better.

Also, when posting on here please indicate the exact problem so we don't have to guess and can help you easier. Telling us what you want without telling us what is/isn't happening doesn't say enough. You could have been getting errors, crashing, compile errors, it starting the `Activity` too soon, etc... Please help us help you

Comment: @KyleK what you're asking is **impossible to do**. Do you know the basics of programming to begin with?

Comment: If `tries` is only changed inside this `onClick()` then the `if` statement only needs to check inside the `onClick()` because that is the only time it will ever be different.

Comment: I was confusing myself @luiggimendoza codeMagic answered my question.thanks.

Comment: Take teaching lessons or something, codeMagic knows how to help. You posted useless comments @luiggiMendoza

Comment: @KyleK learn how to ask a question...

Comment: Easy everyone...deep breaths, we made it! Let's all meet in a chat room for a group hug:D

Comment: @KyleK The issues here weren't due to an inability to teach; that multiple people expressed discontent with the information provided suggests something else may have been the root cause. Code without context actually worse than *no* code.

Comment: @KyleK please accept if this solved your problem. And yes, in the future you need to explain what the problem is a little better because without seeing all of your code (which we don't want) there is no other way for us to understand what you have

Answer (score 3):

Here's is my WAG (Wild-assed-guess) answer, without seeing the rest of your code.

Try moving your if statement inside of `onClick`

So:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tries--;
        triess.setText(tries + "try(s)");

        if (tries == 0) {
            //countDown.cancel();
            //finish();
            Intent openGame = new Intent("com.kyle.expertemoji.loserclass");
            startActivity(openGame);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Intents are case sensitive. Could it be that you are missing the case or spelling mistake. Check in your manifest for exact match.

You can also use

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, ClassName.class);
```